# Can I check if memory block is readable without raising exception with C++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-management

I need the following for the exception handler in C++ code. Say, I have the following code block:

```
void myFunction(LPCTSTR pStr, int ncbNumCharsInStr)
{
    __try
    {
        //Do work with 'pStr'

    }
    __except(1)
    {
        //Catch all

        //But here I need to log `pStr` into event log
        //For that I don't want to raise another exception
        //if memory block of size `ncbNumCharsInStr` * sizeof(TCHAR)
        //pointed by 'pStr' is unreadable.
        if(memory_readable(pStr, ncbNumCharsInStr * sizeof(TCHAR)))
        {
            Log(L"Failed processing: %s", pStr);
        }
        else
        {
            Log(L"String at 0x%X, %d chars long is unreadable!", pStr, ncbNumCharsInStr);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to implement `memory_readable`?

Comment: [`IsBadReadPtr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366713(v=vs.85).aspx/css) doesn't do it for you?

Comment: According to the docs for that page, structured exception handling is the way to go, unless I'm interpreting it incorrectly. I've never had to do this, so I might be.

Comment: Before you try to do this read this post once: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx

Comment: @Naveen, The MSDN articles need to link to Raymond Chen's posts where appropriate :p

Comment: I do not agree with this statement: "...you should just crash when given invalid input" but that's another matter. So, what is better for my example -- wrap my `Log` function in another __try/__except block?

Comment: @c00000fd: incorrect programs do not deserve to run.

Comment: @DanielKO: Tell it to your end-user that just lost their work because of your philosophy, buddy...

Comment: @c00000fd: Do a periodic backup then; the last thing the user wants is a program pretending to be working fine when it's actually just corrupting data. I can still remember those dark days when MS Word 2000 would corrupt long doc files, and you would only find about it if you either came back to edit a corrupted page, or tried to print it.

Answer (score 5):

The [VirtualQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366902%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function might be able to help. The following is a quick stab at how you could implement `memory_readable` using it.

```
bool memory_readable(void *ptr, size_t byteCount)
{
  MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
  if (VirtualQuery(ptr, &mbi, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)) == 0)
    return false;

  if (mbi.State != MEM_COMMIT)
    return false;

  if (mbi.Protect == PAGE_NOACCESS || mbi.Protect == PAGE_EXECUTE)
    return false;

  // This checks that the start of memory block is in the same "region" as the
  // end. If it isn't you "simplify" the problem into checking that the rest of 
  // the memory is readable.
  size_t blockOffset = (size_t)((char *)ptr - (char *)mbi.AllocationBase);
  size_t blockBytesPostPtr = mbi.RegionSize - blockOffset;

  if (blockBytesPostPtr < byteCount)
    return memory_readable((char *)ptr + blockBytesPostPtr,
                           byteCount - blockBytesPostPtr);

  return true;
}
```

NOTE: My background is C, so while I suspect that there are better options than casting to a `char *` in C++ I'm not sure what they are.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. `TCHAR` is simply `wchar_t` or a 2-byte char. I wish I knew more about memory mapping to see how it works. Maybe someone else can analyze it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ReadProcessMemory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) function. If the function returns `0`, the address is not readable otherwise it is readable.

> **Return Value**
>
> If the function fails, the return value is 0 (zero). To get extended
>   error information, call `GetLastError`.
>
> The function fails if the requested read operation crosses into an
>   area of the process that is inaccessible.
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.